# Finding cell values in same sheet multiple times and values next to the found values

Tags: vba, excel

```
Source Port #   Source Port Description Source port Pwwn            Switch Port     Switch Port Description Flolgi port Flogi pwwn
fc1/1   Test_port_description_1 21:00:00:00:12:34:56:78         fc1/1   Test_port_description_1     
fc1/2   Test_port_description_2 21:00:00:00:12:34:56:79         fc1/2   Test_port_description_2 fc1/0,abde  21:00:00:00:12:34:56:78
fc1/3   Test_port_description_3 21:00:00:00:12:34:56:80         fc1/3   Test_port_description   fc1/2,abde  21:00:00:00:12:34:56:79
fc1/4   Test_port_description_4 21:00:00:00:12:34:56:81         fc1/4   Test_port_description_4 fc1/1,abde  21:00:00:00:12:34:56:80
fc1/5   Test_port_description_5 21:00:00:00:12:34:56:82         fc1/5   Test_port_description_5 fc1/4,abde  21:00:00:00:12:34:56:81
                            fc1/5,abde  21:00:00:00:12:34:56:82
```

Here is a sample of the data in my input file. I have an Excel sheet with a command button, and clicking it will activate sheet2 which has my input.

Column A is my source. I want to check each element in that column (A1, A2, etc.) and check if it is found in the sheet. If it is found, I then need to check select next cell value and compare it with next cell value found. If they both are same then both A2,B2 values should be copied to sheet3.
I have to search again in sheet2 and see if it is found then this time I need to check 2 cells to the right of the current element, with the element. Copy them to sheet3.

For example.
A2=fc1/1,B2=Test_port_description_1,c2=21:00:00:00:12:34:56:7
First I want select A2 value and try to find it in sheet.
When find A2=fc1/1 is found in f2=fc1/1 now I need to check if 
B2 value is equal to G2 value. If both of them are same copy both A2 and B2 values to sheet3.

Again I want to continue search A2=fc1/1 is found H5=fc1/1,abde. Now I need to check if C2=21:00:00:00:12:34:56:78 is same as H6=21:00:00:00:12:34:56:78 if same then copy the values C3 next column where values are found, if not found give color coding to the cells.. like red for second column and yellow for 3column in sheet 3...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Option Explicit
Private Sub FindingPortPwwn_Click()

Dim SourcePort As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long, N As Long
Dim counter As Integer
Dim WorkingSheet As Worksheet

'Stopping Application Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'OR You can mention the Sheet name
On Error GoTo SheetNotFound:
Sheets("Final Results Sheet").Delete

'Creating a New Results Worksheet.
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("Input_Worksheet")).Name = "Final Results Sheet"



'Enabling Application alerts once we are done with our task
Application.DisplayAlerts = True




Set WorkingSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
WorkingSheet.Activate
N = WorkingSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'MsgBox (N)
For i = 1 To N
    'MsgBox (WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value)
    'MsgBox (WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value)
  Set SourcePort = WorkingSheet.Cells.Find(WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value, WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A"), LookIn:=xlValues)
    'MsgBox (SourcePort.Address)
    firstaddress = SourcePort.Address
    Do
    If (InStr(SourcePort.Value, ",")) Then
       If WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 2).Value = SourcePort.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Value = WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 2) = WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 2).Value

       Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Value = WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 2).Value = WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 2).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 126, 135)
        End If


    Else
      If WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = SourcePort.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Value = WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 1) = WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value

      Else
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Value = WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = WorkingSheet.Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(i, "A").Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      End If
    End If

    Set SourcePort = WorkingSheet.Cells.FindNext(SourcePort)
    Loop While Not SourcePort Is Nothing And firstaddress <> SourcePort.Address
    MsgBox (SourcePort.Value)  
Next i
    Exit Sub
    SheetNotFound:
      MsgBox (" Final Results Worksheet not Found")
    End Sub
```

Comment: I am able to send the correct data to sheet3, but i have having difficulty in setting color code for not found values. I am unable to change the color as per the logic.